# DllImport wrong encoding

Tags: c#, string, encoding, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm having trouble using Dll-Imported win api function to work correctly, and it's probably related to the way strings are encoded.

Actually I'm trying to use CreateProcess from kernel32.dll.
It's imported the following way:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
      public static extern bool CreateProcess(
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string ApplicationName,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string CommandLine,
         ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES ProcessAttributes,
         ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES ThreadAttributes,
         bool InheritHandles,
         uint CreationFlags,
         IntPtr Environment,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string CurrentDirectory,
         [In] ref StartupInfo StartupInfo,
         out PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation);
```

In the code, the call is as follow:

```
var fileName = PInvokeEncode(FileName);
var arguments =  PInvokeEncode(Arguments);
workingDirectory = PInvokeEncode(workingDirectory);
//var arguments = Arguments.ToString(pinvokeEncoding);
if (!ProcessUtility.CreateProcess(
        fileName,
        ref arguments,
        ref processAttributes,
        ref threadAttributes,
        true, //inherit handles
        (uint)(CreationFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CreationFlags.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT),
        IntPtr.Zero, //inherits current environement
        workingDirectory,
        ref startupInfo,
        out processInformation))
{
    throw new Win32Exception("CreateProcessAsUser");
}

...
...
...

private static readonly Encoding PInvokeEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;

private static string PInvokeEncode(string value)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
    var encodedString = PInvokeEncoding.GetString(bytes);
    return encodedString;
}
```

In a fixture I then launch a test calling CreateProcess with
Filename = `@"c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"` and Arguments = `@"/C ""c:\Windows\System32\ping.exe /?"""`

As you can see, in the task manager, when I launch a new cmd.exe, the value shown in the command line column is invalid:
[image: The cmd shown in the task manager, with wrong command line value]

It should show `c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "c:\Windows\System32\ping.exe /?"`

Any idea on how to correct the encoding for the task manager to show the correct string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your p/invoke is wrong. You've asked for the Unicode version of the function, but also asked to pass ANSI strings. Your screenshot does not correspond to the code in the question. If you really used the code in the question it would not be possible for the system to decode either string.

The other mistake is the use of `ref` on the second argument. You must remove that.

The version from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateProcess.html) is good:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool CreateProcess(
   string lpApplicationName,
   string lpCommandLine,
   ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, 
   ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
   bool bInheritHandles, 
   uint dwCreationFlags,
   IntPtr lpEnvironment,
   string lpCurrentDirectory,
   [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, 
   out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

You might prefer to use `IntPtr SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` in place of `ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` so that you can pass `IntPtr.Zero` for those arguments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to pinvoke.net !  
I removed all extra custom encoding conversion and also had to remove the ref behind lpCommandLine in addition to adjust format of some other structs as shown on pinvoke.net